# How does FindViewById() work?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm new in mobile app development. I'm using Xamarin to develop Android applications. In the hello world app in the OnCreate method I see the following code:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
```

So I'm trying to create my own button the same way. I create the button in the designer and inside OnCreate method put the line:

```
Button myOwnBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyOwnBtn);
```

That gives me an error that there is no MyOwnBtn. Then I'm looking the code of Id class and see there a line like:

```
public const int MyButton=2123344112;
```

If I put there the line:

```
public const int MyOwnBtn=2123344113;
```

Everything works fine. But as I understand it should be generated automatically or it will be a little bit difficult to put there a unique number for each control.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? And how does FindViewById() work?

Comment: Resource.Id.MyOwnBtn is the ID (MyOwnBtn) you have to define it for your button when you create new button..

Comment: If you can't find the button that's why you have not set the content view with the layout that has that button declared, so it also can't be shown, interacted, etc. Use SetContentView (Resource.Layout.MyLayout); with that MyOwnBtn created in the MyLayout XML file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the `id` `MyOwnBtn` to the `Button` that you created in the designer.

`findViewById` is a method of the `View` class and it looks for a child view having the `id` that you provided in the argument.

From [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)):

> Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view.

Answer (score 0):

MyButton id is not a const value, It will change every launch.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity or ViewGroup's findViewById() method returns a view that already has an id. The findViewById() method should be used in conjunction with XML layouts to provide a reference to the View that was defined in the XML file.

**Edit**: Not entirely sure if my answer is relevant to Xamarin. I apologize if I have mislead people, I am referring to Java Android application development.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a **button** in your **.xml** file, you should set an id for it (Usually it is done using **string.xml** file). After that, **R.java** will be updated automatically and set a number to your declared id and you can access your button by that id like what you have done.

Comment: I set an Id property in properties tab. But nothing was updated. @HaMi

Answer (score 0):

It will try to find it from the XML file that you inflate. So make sure you inflate the correct xml file. This code inflates the xml:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.MainLayout);
```

Even if you got the correct id created in a xml file, if you don't inflate it first, the system won't be able to find that view since it is not inflated.