# EditText always set to null

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-edittext, nullreferenceexception

I keep getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            payroll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payroll>(Intent.GetStringExtra("payroll"));
            EditText name2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.name2);
            EditText age2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.age2);
            EditText finalPCB2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.finalPCB2);
            EditText finalEPF2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.finalEPF2);
            EditText finalSOCSO2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.finalSOCSO2);
            EditText finalEIS2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.finalEIS2);
            EditText grossSalary2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.grossSalary2);
            EditText netSalary2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.netSalary2);
            EditText employerEPF2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.employerEPF2);
            EditText employerSOCSO2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.employerSOCSO2);
            EditText employerEIS2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.employerEIS2);
            name2.Text = " ";
            age2.Text = " ";
            finalPCB2.Text = " ";
            finalEPF2.Text = " ";
            finalSOCSO2.Text = " ";
            finalEIS2.Text = " ";
            grossSalary2.Text = " ";
            netSalary2.Text = " ";
            employerEPF2.Text = " ";
            employerSOCSO2.Text = " ";
            employerEIS2.Text = " ";

            Button _reviewBack = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.reviewBack);

            _reviewBack.Click += PlayButton_Click;
            _reviewBack.Click += (sender, e) => {
                var payrollReview = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(payrollReview);
            };

            void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MediaPlayer _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Drawable.buttonclick);
                _player.Start();
            }

        }
```

And here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name2"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/age2"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/finalPCB2"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finalEPF2"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finalSOCSO2"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finalEIS2"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grossSalary2"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/netSalary2"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Employer Details:"
        android:textSize="63px"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/employerEPF2"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/employerSOCSO2"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/employerEIS2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="50px"/>
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reviewBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back To Employees"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I hover over my name2 edittext it shows that it is null, like this:[image]

But it shouldn't be null, and I can't find the problem here.

**Update:**
So it turns out I forgot to add the SetContentView in my OnCreate method, but I am still getting the same error. Am I putting the SetContentView in the right place?

Comment: I'd check if any of your variables are not null, it's possible you're just not using 'findViewById' correctly, or that none of your views have instantiated by this point. If some are null and some are populated then you have a point  of comparison

Comment: @TheLemon All of my variables are null

Comment: is there any way to tell weather the view is initiated?

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278612/how-does-findviewbyid-work

Comment: Looks like someone else has had the same problem

Comment: @TheLemon where do I put the SetContentView?

Comment: I am putting it on the first line of the OnCreate method

Comment: @puko I updated it with the xml

Comment: @TheLemon I don't think the problem is because of FindViewByID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code above seems to be missing `SetContentView()` in `OnCreate()` method and call `FindViewById` after it.

It should look something like this：

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.xxxx); //this is the layout XML for your activity
        EditText name2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.name2);
        ...
        name2.Text = ""; // here the name2 will not be null;
        
    }
```

Comment: @dan51 Could you update your code of onCreate above ?

Comment: I rebuilt my project and it's working now! Thanks for this :)